# Concat'ing strings with strcpy or memcpy

Tags: c

I am trying to join a string using `strcpy` using the following approach:

```
char * concat(char ** buffer) {

    char * joined_string = malloc(50);

    int offset=0;
    while (*buffer) {
        strcpy(joined_string+offset, *buffer++); // seg fault, how to advance offset?
        offset += strlen(*buffer);
    }

    return joined_string;
}
```

Is there a way to keep advancing via an offset to keep writing to the string buffer? If so, how would that be done?

Comment: Why not just use `strcat`?

Comment: You should keep a track of how much space you've allocated (50 bytes) and worry about whether there's enough space for the extra data you're adding to the end.  You could use `strlen()` on `*buffer` (no increment yet) and then use `memcpy()` to copy the data, and increment by the length.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for your feedback. Two questions about your comment -- (1) any reason for using `memcpy` over `strcpy`, or are the two basically interchangable here? (2) What do you mean by " You could use strlen() on *buffer (no increment yet) and then use memcpy()" -- how would that look?

Comment: If you know the source string length — and you must know its length to know whether it is safe to copy — then `memmove()` or `memcpy()` can be quicker than `strcpy()` because it doesn't need to keep checking whether the byte being copied is null or not; it just counts the bytes.  With modern optimizing compilers, it isn't always clear which will do best — there may not be very much difference at all. Code: `while (*buffer) { size_t len = strlen(*buffer); if (…check for space…) { …error handling… } memcpy(joined_string + offset, *buffer++, len + 1); offset += len; }` — `len + 1` copies `'\0'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main bug is that you're advancing `offset` by the length of the *next* string in `buffer` instead of by the one you just appended.

Comment: Or more precisely, when you get to the end of the buffer, calling `strlen(NULL)` on the NULL sentinel that marks the end of the buffer array...